# Answering a question which has hints in comments

Tags: discussion, comments

I think it happens to most of users (me being a fresher in this field).
Some questions have a lot of hints in comments and if one answer that question using those hints.

Or it also happens when a starter developer like me reads a question and tries to solve the question between that time few users posts comments which really gives away the answer which you also have answer too but comments had been posted between time one reads question and gets  their answer .

So is it a good practice to post your answer?
My opinion is i feel like cheating as reading those comments really helps and improves my answers which i was going to post .

Comment: If you don't have more to say then a comment already does then leave it. If you can extend that to a good answer then there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: But then, after having submitted a question, how to grant as "accepted" a comment containing the right answer?

Comment: @juergend Thanks that's pretty much clears everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a problem to post an answer when there are also hints in the comments.  Just make sure that you aren't plagiarizing them.

here are a couple good rules of thumb

- If you would have posted the answer anyway if the comments weren't there it's fine to answer.
- If the comments help you but are incomplete **or** if you would have posted the answer anyway if the comments were an answer instead, than it's fine to answer.

Comment: -1 This is saying basically the same thing as juergen d's comment.  ;)

Comment: This answer may be a case which i am discussing. Yes ` juergen d` answered pretty much in comments but `Sam` my be writing the answer at the same time.  However i do not have any proof to say that except i can think difference between both comments and answer is of seconds as i can judge roughly .

Comment: I think i got the answer from both `comment` and `Answer` here, I think (and its only my thinking, and i am open to suggestions and correction) `juergen d` is absolutely correct and as `Bill` said answer is similar to comment , However i feel `Sam` took time to put a bit more effort and completed the task of answering a question which completes the requirement. This is the only difference i can see.

Comment: @SurajSingh Just to clarify, my comment above was only a joke. We do *strongly* prefer questions to have proper answers rather than just comments.  If comments are leading in the right direction, it's worth the time to flesh them out into a full answer.

Comment: And going by the amount of time between the comment and that answer, I'd have to have a pretty impressive WPM to have copied from juergen's comment

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar case once. I urged (via another comment) the user who posted the comment to post it in a more complete manner as a new answer.
This way there's no risk of plagiarizing and any upvotes/reps due to the answers goes to the right user.

If the user is unwilling to go along - then I guess [Sam I am's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208908/202617) is what you may do next.